# Xamarin. Как из ViewModel передавать данные в Model?

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin, viewmodel

Доброе время суток. Не могу победить одну задачку:

1. Есть **Model** (некий partial class, который наследует ContentPage), **View** и **ViewModel**;
2. По нажатии на кнопку в **View** через **Command** **ViewModel** делает некоторые рассчеты.
3. Рассчеты, полученные в **п.2** нужно передать в новое окно (*Navigation Page*).

Как правильно реализовать это без применения сторонних плагинов и сохраняя концепцию MVVM чистой?

Конечно, я мог бы обойтись без ViewModel, тогда реализация довольно ясна. Но мне бы хотелось именно через **MVVM**. Прочитал, что вызывать алерты и окна из ViewModel не стоит, нужно передать полученные данные в Model, откуда и инициировать Navigation Page.

Я сделал это так:

1. Передаю в ViewModel в качестве параметра конструктора экземпляр Model;
2. В ViewModel делаю нужные рассчеты и оперирую Model, в том числе из ViewModel вызываю Model.Navigation.

Насколько такой подход корректен?

Прочитал еще, что можно из ViewModel обновлять свойства Model, и из Model реагировать на это, в т.ч. например включать триггер для открытия Navigation.

P.S. Предварительно читал эти статьи: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx и https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/simplemvvmexample/ Но там описывается MVVM в WPF, что немного не то, если я правильно понял, хотя и пробовал применить их.

Просьба подсказать как правильно?

PS Еще вопрос:

Я подключаю BindingContext из XAML таким образом:

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ViewModels:NewsViewModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
```

Как мне в таком случае передать в конструктор **NewsViewModel** объект моей модели Model?

Т.е. сделать то же самое, что в С#

```
NewsViewModel VM = new NewsViewModel(this);
this.BindingContext = VM;
```

Comment: Вот что не следует делать так это: "...полученные данные в Model, откуда и инициировать Navigation Page." Модель об устройстве UI, наличии каких-то Page не должна знать ничего.

Comment: @Bulson А как быть с навигацией тогда? Navigation.PushAsync вызывается только из ContentPage, коей и является Model, или я не прав? Как тогда лучше перейти на другую страницу после совершения некоторых рассчетов в ViewModel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтобы понять какой-либо тех.приём или применение того или иного шаблона нужно прежде всего уяснить для себя ради чего это делается, какая конечная цель преследуется.

Все эти MVC, MVP, MVVM направлены лишь на одно, на разделение ответственности, на разделение на части программного кода по функциональным обязанностям. Применительно к MVVM можно сказать следующее.

С `View` всё просто - это интерфейс, UI. Такое изобретение Microsoft как `Dependency Property` сделало возможным существование слоя `ViewModel` - это отделение от `View` всех обязанностей по непосредственной работе с данными отображающимися во View. Нужные свойства контролов из `View` представлены во `ViewModel` в виде свойств класса `ViewModel`, причем эти свойства "оповещают" привязанные к ним контролы об изменении своих значений с помощью вызова события `PropertyChanged`.

C `Model` всё несколько сложнее. В большинстве примеров по MVVM то, что там выдается за модель в чистом виде ей не является, а является продолжением всё той же `ViewModel`, так как по своей структуре и содержанию (классы со свойствами вызывающими `PropertyChanged`) соответствует контейнеру данных, которые отображаются во View. Для простых приложений это вполне годный вариант.

Когда же встает вопрос работы с базой данных, в особенности с реляционной СУБД, то на структуру и содержание классов модели налагаются требования обусловленные той или иной СУБД. Наиболее очевидное - это соответствие таблицы в базе данных и класса модели, т.е. класс являет собой отражение таблицы. И тут нередко возникает диссонанс между классами, с которыми работает `ViewModel`, и классами хранения в БД, т.е. UI отображает данные не так как они в конечном итоге хранятся в БД.

Ко всему прочему, что касается модели, следует упомянуть еще и так называемую `Business Logic`. В более-менее сложных программных продуктах данные не просто отображаются и изменяются пользователем, но и подразумевают над собой определенного рода вычисления, обработку по тем или иным бизнес правилам. И здесь снова возникает своя модель данных, свои классы, которые не похожи на классы хранения в БД и классы отображения в UI.

Из всего выше сказанного вы должны понять только одну мысль, что все эти шаблоны призваны лишь для одного - для правильного и логичного разделения ответственности между тем или иным классом входящим в кодовую базу приложения.

Вернемся к MVVM. Те классы, которые вы складируете в папку Models в своем проекте - это **контейнеры данных** вашего приложения **и больше ничего**. Модель ничего не знает ни о каких-либо страницах, кнопках и проч. Это просто контейнер с набором свойств, в которых хранятся данные приложения, во время его работы. Под `ViewModel` вы должны понимать класс, который работает с классом(ами) модели, а также с другими сервисными классами, которые могут отвечать за работу с сетью, с хранением данных и проч. Если вам необходимо из логики работы во `ViewModel` каким-то образом "обратиться" к пользователю программы с помощью окна запроса, переключится на др. страницу и проч. вам для этого нужно использовать в качестве посредника соответствующие классы, которые будут по запросу `ViewModel` обращаться к `View` за необходимой вам операцией, но это опять же ни в коем случае не может быть класс контейнер данных из модели.

Создайте интерфейс `INavigator` и объявите в нем нужные методы для переключения на нужную страницу. Далее создайте класс `Navigator : INavigator` реализуйте интерфейс в нем, далее в конструктор `ViewModel` пропишите параметр типа `INavigator`, потом либо с помощью какого-либо контейнера DI, либо просто руками передавайте при создании экземпляра `ViewModel` экземпляр `Navigator`. В нужном месте `ViewModel` вызывайте метод из `INavigator`. Это всё.

Comment: Вполне исчерпывающе, спасибо!